# Sasha Grey account needs to be given a thought

Tags: discussion

https://islam.stackexchange.com/users/23351/sasha-grey

Fake username and fake picture. Can moderators do something like suspend that account till an acceptable name is used?

Answer (score 3):

I've seen this issue come up from time to time at [math.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11562/91818) (there was a user who chose usernames like [Kim Jong Il](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kim_Jong-il), but misspelled it).  It was not considered a big deal, except in cases of:

1. **impersonation** esp. of someone in authority, or

   (From [legal](https://stackexchange.com/legal): Under no circumstances will Subscriber use the Network or the Service to ... create a false identity or to impersonate another person)
2. **offensiveness**.

E.g. [Mad Scientist](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15096/91818) wrote:

> There are very few rules on user names, duplicates are explicitly allowed. But there are some restrictions:
>
> - Impersonation of other users is not allowed (having the same name is not necessarily impersonation)
> - The diamond symbol indicating a moderator can't be used in user names
> - Offensive user names will be forcibly changed by moderators. The decision on whether a user name is offensive is made on a case-by-case basis by the moderators.

So...

**Does using this particular username amount to impersonation?**  From your post, I doubt it ("Fake username and fake picture.")  You don't seem "fooled" by it, and I don't think a reasonable person would be.

Moreover, that person is not considered an Islamic authority.

---

General Meta.SE posts on this topic are:

- [Is it ok to impersonate a public figure?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13039/351283)
- [How far should we go in disallowing 'impersonation' in profiles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279108/351283)

Other posts:

- [Meta.math.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22595/91818) used the name of a recently deceased famous mathematician.
- [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/201966/351283) about using an image of a kidnapped child.
- [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204572/351283) about the username Jesus Christ.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know it is a fake profile? Did you verify it is not Sasha Grey? Until verified, I'd focus on her Q&A value.